# Raspberry Pi Zero W, Pi camera with motion error

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I got Motion working on my Raspberry Pi Zero W Stretch. Everything was working fine untill I shut it down to take a break. After i turned it back on it doesn't suddenly work. This is the error I get.

````
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] conf_load: Processing thread 0 - config file 
/home/pi/.motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [ALR] [ALL] conf_cmdparse: Unknown config option "
"
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Logging to syslog
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Motion 4.2.2 Started
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using default log type (ALL)
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_startup: Using log type (ALL) log level (NTC)
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] webu_start_strm: Starting all camera streams on port 8081
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] webu_start_strm: Unable to start stream for camera 0
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] webu_start_ctrl: Starting webcontrol on port 8080
[0:motion] [NTC] [STR] webu_start_ctrl: Unable to start MHD
[0:motion] [NTC] [ENC] ffmpeg_global_init: ffmpeg libavcodec version 57.64.101 libavformat version 57.56.101
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] translate_init: Language: English
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 is from /home/pi/.motion/motion.conf
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] motion_start_thread: Camera ID: 0 Camera Name: (null) Device: /dev/video0
[0:motion] [NTC] [ALL] main: Waiting for threads to finish, pid: 687
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] motion_init: Camera 0 started: motion detection Enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] vid_start: Opening MMAL cam
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] mmalcam_start: MMAL Camera thread starting... for camera (vc.ril.camera) of 640 x 480 at 10 fps
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] create_camera_component: camera component couldn't be enabled
[1:ml1] [NTC] [VID] mmalcam_cleanup: MMAL Camera cleanup
[1:ml1] [ERR] [VID] vid_start: MMAL cam failed to open
[1:ml1] [WRN] [ALL] motion_init: Could not fetch initial image from camera
[1:ml1] [WRN] [ALL] motion_init: Motion continues using width and height from config file(s)
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 1 items
[1:ml1] [NTC] [ALL] image_ring_resize: Resizing pre_capture buffer to 4 items```
````

Comment: The error message on the second line is important . Please show your `motion.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

May be Ribbon cable connecting camera got loose. Also check camera is enabled in config(raspi-config)

if the red LED on the camera glowing, things should be fine. You can verify camera functionality with rpistill